# Hiding my birthday

Tags: facebook

How can I hide my birthday and prevent Facebook from notifying my friends when I have a birthday?

I tried "Settings -> Privacy", but it only gives very general settings - there is nothing specific about birthday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change who can see your birthday by adjusting the audience.

Go to your profile and click **About**. On the left pane, click **Contact and Basic Info**.

There are 2 audience selectors next to your birthday (under **Basic Information**):

- one for the day and month
- one for the year

Friends won't get a notification about your upcoming birthday if you don't share **the day and month** with them. Click **Edit** and just choose **"Only Me" next to the day and month**, and your friends shouldn't get notifications about your birthday after you save changes.

For convenience, the following is a screeny of the related section:

[image]